# asp.net identity 2.0 and The data protection operation was unsuccessful. error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-identity, owin

i have a site i just deployed to azure.  when i try to register a new user in the application i am getting

> The data protection operation was unsuccessful.

i have scoured for the last few hours and found a number of similar answers regarding WIF and machine keys.  i have tried making the updates to my web.config  as recommended by this post http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/01/28/running-wif-based-apps-in-windows-azure-web-sites-4/. but that doesn't seem to help.

when i started the project i started with a blank project and install the asp.net identity 2.0 samples package which was at the time 2.0.0 beta2.

if code samples are needed i will provide, i just don't know which code is relevant for this problem, other than i know the failure is occurring when the boiler plate registration method is trying to generate a confirmation token.

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    RecaptchaVerificationHelper recaptchaHelper = this.GetRecaptchaVerificationHelper();


    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(recaptchaHelper.Response)) // if captcha is empty
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Captcha answer cannot be empty.");
    }
    else // else captcha is not empty
    {
        RecaptchaVerificationResult recaptchaResult = recaptchaHelper.VerifyRecaptchaResponse(); // verify captcha

        if (recaptchaResult != RecaptchaVerificationResult.Success)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Incorrect captcha answer.");
        }
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser
        {
            UserName = model.Email,
            Email = model.Email,
            Company = new Company
            {
                CompanyName = model.CompanyName,
                CreateDate = DateTime.Now,
                SubscriptionStatus = SubscriptionStatus.Free,
                Address1 = model.Address1 ?? string.Empty,
                Address2 = model.Address2 ?? string.Empty,
                City = model.City ?? string.Empty,
                StateId = model.StateId,
                PostalCode = model.PostalCode,
                BusinessType = model.BusinessType,
                OperatingDistance = model.OperatingDistance,
                Phone = PhoneNumber.ToStorage(model.Phone),
                Fax = model.Fax == null ? string.Empty : PhoneNumber.ToStorage(model.Fax),
                PrimaryContactName = model.PrimaryContactName,
                PrimaryContactPhone = PhoneNumber.ToStorage(model.PrimaryContactPhone),
                PrimaryContactTitle = model.PrimaryContactTitle
            }
        };

        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
            var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
            await _userManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Email, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking this link: <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">link</a>");
            ViewBag.Email = model.Email;
            return View("DisplayEmail");
        }
        AddErrors(result);
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    rePopRegistrationViewModel(model);
    return View(model);
}
```

where the data protection provider is set: IdentityConfig.cs

```
public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
{
    var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new bcUserStore(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
    // Configure validation logic for usernames
    manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
    {
        AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
        RequireUniqueEmail = true
    };
    // Configure validation logic for passwords
    manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
    {
        RequiredLength = 6,
        RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
        RequireDigit = true,
        RequireLowercase = true,
        RequireUppercase = true,
    };
    // Configure user lockout defaults
    manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
    manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;
    // Register two factor authentication providers. This application uses Phone and Emails as a step of receiving a code for verifying the user
    // You can write your own provider and plug in here.
    manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("PhoneCode", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
    {
        MessageFormat = "Your security code is: {0}"
    });
    manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("EmailCode", new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
    {
        Subject = "SecurityCode",
        BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
    });
    manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
    manager.SmsService = new SmsService();
    var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
    if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
    {
        manager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser, string>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.Net Identity"));
    }
    return manager;
}
```

Startup.Auth.cs

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app) 
{
    // Configure the db context, user manager and role manager to use a single instance per request
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);


    // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
    // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
    // Configure the sign in cookie
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider {
            // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
            // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
            OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
        }
    });
    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

    // Enables the application to temporarily store user information when they are verifying the second factor in the two-factor authentication process.
    app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

    // Enables the application to remember the second login verification factor such as phone or email.
    // Once you check this option, your second step of verification during the login process will be remembered on the device where you logged in from.
    // This is similar to the RememberMe option when you log in.
    app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);

    // Uncomment the following lines to enable logging in with third party login providers
    //app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(
    //    clientId: "",
    //    clientSecret: "");

    //app.UseTwitterAuthentication(
    //   consumerKey: "",
    //   consumerSecret: "");

    //app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
    //   appId: "",
    //   appSecret: "");

    //app.UseGoogleAuthentication();
}
```

Comment: Can I see the code where you set the DataProtectionProvider? Probably in Startup.cs . My guess is that you are using a data protection provider that won't work across a web farm type deployment.

Comment: code added.  DataProtectionProvider is set in IdentityConfig.cs in the canned Identity Sample from NuGet

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: I think for this issue i used a newer asp.net identity sample from nuget.